# I am getting InvalidOperation error on deserializing a xml string to class object

Tags: c#, xml, ebay-api

I am continuously getting invalidOperation error while converting XML to a class object.

I have tried : [Deserialize XML String into Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484417/deserialize-xml-string-into-class) but it didn't work

Below is my code for deserializing

```
XElement categoryList = XElement.Load(stream);
XNamespace ebayns = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
XElement list =  categoryList.Descendants(ebayns + "CategoryArray").First();  

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CategoryList));
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(list.ToString()))
{
        CategoryList _categoryNode = (CategoryList)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

below is my CategoryList Model

```
[XmlRoot("CategoryArray")]
public class CategoryList
{
    [XmlElement("Category")]
    public List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();

}
```

Sample Xml request

```
<CategoryArray xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Category xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <CategoryID>-1</CategoryID>
        <CategoryLevel>0</CategoryLevel>
        <CategoryName>Root</CategoryName>
        <CategoryParentID>0</CategoryParentID>
        <LeafCategory>false</LeafCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <CategoryID>20081</CategoryID>
        <CategoryLevel>1</CategoryLevel>
        <CategoryName>Antiques</CategoryName>
        <CategoryParentID>-1</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryNamePath>Antiques</CategoryNamePath>
        <CategoryIDPath>20081</CategoryIDPath>
        <LeafCategory>false</LeafCategory>
    </Category>
</CategoryArray>
```

I need to get a list of category class object

Comment: I've tried your code without first three lines. It works ok.

Comment: do you think the error is in the first three lines?

Comment: Not sure. You have to define what exactly line of your code throws an exception. Debug your code. Set a breakpoint at first line and go through your code line by line.

Comment: Try without the namespace.  The xml you posted does not contain any namespaces.

Comment: @Dmitry  ` CategoryList _categoryNode = (CategoryList)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader); ` is thorwing exception. @jdweng : orignal xml has namespace , the one i posted is a sample. do you think namespace can be issue ?

Comment: Try to delete all `xmlns` from your xml. Because your request without `xmlns` that you posted initially is going ok.

Comment: stripping namespace from the XML solved the issue but adds an extra traversal to remove namespace. Looking for any better solution than this

Comment: have you tried specifying the namespace on the `XmlElementAttribute`?